# How can I change the line weight of my mouse cursor?

Tags: windows-10, mouse-cursor

My new laptop (an HP Spectre x360 15") has a 2160p display, and I'm finding it difficult to quickly find the location of the cursor in some instances.  I think this is because, despite setting the scaling to 200%, the cursor still uses lines that are a single pixel wide.

I can set the cursor to be bigger, but this doesn't change the line weight either.  I can also set the cursor to be black or high contrast, both of which would probably help, but I'd prefer to keep it the standard white cursor.

Is there any way to change the line weight of the cursor?

Comment: I've avoided loading Win 10, so I don't know if this applies.  However, many desktops include a feature you can enable where holding a specific key for a second triggers some form of very visible brief highlight of the cursor to make its current position obvious.  It doesn't require changing the cursor appearance if you're happy with it.

Comment: That sounds like it might be third party software, but something to keep in mind.  I'll try out the cursor shadow for a few days and see how much that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't exactly change the line weight, but should help with the visibility of your cursor: Turn on the pointer shadow, which should add at least a few pixels to the bottom right side of the cursor.  This might be in different places, depending on you system, but I found it by searching for "mouse" in the Windows settings (part of the device section in the settings), and selecting the additional settings link.  That brought up this dialog:

[image: Mouse Properties Dialog]

Just click that checkbox near the bottom, then OK, and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is use a different Cursor scheme.

Open the Mouse Properties section, and at the top where it says Scheme, change the Scheme to a larger one. The mouse cursor will be increased but so will the border around it. Alternatively, you may want to use the inverted cursor which inverts the pixels under the cursor, making it far easier to find the cursor about 90% of the time. This too can be set in size.

[image: Mouse Properties Dialog]

*I used the image provided by MBreadley's answer as it shows the Scheme pretty well, and my image would almost be the same anyway. Hope you don't mind. :)*